# How to list directories and files within a RoR Ruby on Rails app a la Apache style?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm pretty new to RoR, and I have a directory that I would like to list its contents when I put the path of the directory in the URL bar of a web browser.  I'm used to Apache where I could just setup a .htaccess file to show the contents of a directory, and have the files within the directory linkable / browseable when browsing the directory.  I'm sure there's a similar solution using RoR but I haven't come across one.

Comment: I am using passenger / "mod_rails"

Comment: .htaccess is the web server and the browser interacting, I would think you could still have this regardless of Rails. If you want a solution built in Rails you could make a `File` model and controller with actions to list and browse the directories. Ruby has classes like `Dir` and `File` to handle much of what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger can be configured so that it gets turned off in some folders:

```
<Location /shared>
  PassengerEnabled off
  Options +Indexes
</Location>
```

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerEnabled

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT*** 
I didn't read enough and did not realize that the file manager I recommended is for PHP not Rails.
The answer is still, if you want to browse files and directories in Rails you will need to write your own or find a gem that gives you that functionality. There is no built in "file browser" module for Rails.

---

Comment: Are you saying, RoR doesn't have a built-in way of displaying files in a directory?

Comment: Yes. RoR is just a framework. If you want to have a webpage that displays something, it has to have a `view` associated with it. I don't know enough about web servers (like passenger) to know if that particular web server will allow you to do that. When you ask a Rails app for a path (a route in Rails) it will pass that request to a controller that supports what ever actions you define. It is an MVC framework. If your web server can do directory listing along side your Rails app, then that would work also.

Comment: Are you looking to add this functionality to a Rails app? Or are you looking for a Rails app that does all of this for you? One open source app is Boxroom (http://boxroomapp.com) There are also some file managers written in Javascript if that suits you better.